# Is there a general rule to calculate heat dissipation of electronic equipment?

Tags: power, heat, power-dissipation, specifications

Is there a general rule for calculating heat dissipation in electronic equipment if it's not listed in the specs?

I have a couple of projects coming I'm working on that require this. For one situation I need to provide the heat dissipated for some routers, switches, UPSs, and two-way radio repeaters I'm installing in leased rack space in a equipment room.

I also have a situation where I need to install a router and UPS in a storage cabinet in an RV type vehicle. In that case I think it's important to be reasonably accurate. As far as I can tell, this information isn't listed on spec sheets by Cisco, Motorola, or even APC, so I assume I need to calculate it myself some way.

Since the formula for power to heat is ***1W = 3.41 BTU/hr*** my first pass at calculations was just to multiply the equipment power consumption by 3.41 to get BTU per hour.  However, I guess that would only apply if the equipment were 100% efficient at being a heater. So my guess is that the correct way to calculate would be to use the power efficiency, ***η*** to calculate, where ***(1-η) x 3.41 x Watts = BTU/hr***.  For example  if a 1000 Watt UPS has efficiency ***η=.9***, then I would think its heat dissipated would be ***(1-.9) x 3.41 x 1000 = 341 BTU/hr***.  If this is correct, is there a rule of thumb for estimating the efficiency of certain types of equipment?

Comment: Your approach looks right but why convert to the quaint BTU/hr? Just calculate the dissipation in the cabinet (watts) and that's the amount of cooling power required (in watts). If you need to convert to energy then multiply by 3600 for kWh.

Comment: Mostly, power ratings are maximums for input power (i.e. they are fuse ratings) rather than heat-dissipated-in-the-box.   A 1000 watt UPS doesn't dissipate much until it goes into battery-drives-output mode, and dissipation depends on the load, which is NEVER accurately "1000W".

Comment: The efficiency is maximum 50% when there is impedance matching with the load.

Comment: In addition to Andy's answer, analyze each load with a watt-meter.  You'll find that a 1kW "computer" PSU might consume maybe 750W at 8am peak load, 500W average, and 200W on nights and weekends, etc.

Comment: @MissMulan There is no mention of any sort of system that would involve impedance matching in the question; why bring that up?

Comment: Hearth I was just saying you cannot have >50% efficiency in electric circuits

Comment: @Miss Mulan - But you can have >50% efficiency in a power supply.  80%-90% efficiencies seem to be standard.  And impedance matching doesn't apply to power systems.

Comment: I am not talking about the power factor.

Comment: @MissMulan Neither is anyone else. The maximum power transfer theorem is straightforward to derive when you've covered some calculus. The real trick is learning when it doesn't apply. Like here.

Comment: @Transistor "why convert to the quaint BTU/hr?" Because air-conditioning equipment may be rated in BTU/hr rather than kW. (Unless it's rated in - rolls eyes - tons (i.e. of ice melted per 24 hrs).)

Comment: The important consideration is the temperature rise above ambient in the enclosure at a certain power dissipation. You can try to calculate this if you know the R-rating of the enclosure, but it might be easier to put a resistor (heater) of known wattage at a certain voltage, and let it run until temperature stabilizes. From that you can determine degrees per watt, and figure the worst case ambient and maximum temperature you can tolerate in the enclosure.

Comment: If you're going to have to do a units conversion, convert the furlongs per fortnight (or whatever) of your cooling system to Watts so that you're working in SI everywhere, and not the other way around.

Comment: @Neil_UK: If you've figured out what equipment you want in a data centre, and then need to go shopping for cooling systems, it's easier to do the conversion once, not converting the BTU/hr rating of every different AC unit you look at back into Watts to compare against your load.  It's ridiculous that not everything is rated in Watts in the first place, and you can still *think about* your load in Watts, but you still might want a BTU/hr number sometimes instead of punishing yourself because other people suck and don't use SI.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> As far as I can tell, this information isn't listed on spec sheets

Oh but it is! The worst case is the power rating on the rating label. If a device can consume 100VA worst case, then that's how much heat it will dump, worst case. You can assume that VA=W and convert that to BTU/hr, horsepower, etc.

The only case in IT equipment where it's not true is PoE switches: they dump some of that power wherever the loads are. Other than that, all electrical devices in the racks of a data center are 100% efficient heaters.

All of the electricity you pump into a stand-alone data center gets dumped right out through the HVAC system. Thermodynamically speaking, the amount of "work" that the computers actually do by "computing" is so astronomically minuscule, that we don't need to think about it.

If you're nitpicking then yes, a few hundred watts will go out to the IP cameras on and around the building. But you're not gonna save any money by taking it into account in thermal calculations for a data center. For an office server closet - it may be important if there's lots of PoE equipment hanging off the switches. But you won't go wrong if you just go conservative and assume power into the closet = heat to be taken out of the closet.

Comment: OK.  I was looking around, and found this link below, where they were saying to estimate that 10% of the power is converted to heat.  But reading closer it looks like they are talking a power distrobution system.

Comment: Here's the link I was referring to:  https://instrumentationtools.com/how-to-calculate-heat-load-in-electricalelectronic-panel-enclosure/

Comment: This article is talking more about general electrical power equipment, transformers, switchgear, and so on. The important thing here is hat they are "on the way" to where the power is  actually used. Those loads will very often be 100% heaters, the remaining 90% (except for spare change) but the switch-gear, transformers, etc, will steal only very little of the power. In your datacentre say you have a 1MW transformer.That might disipate 25kW of heat when under load, but its 1MW load (a load of racks) will then do the business of disipating the rest of it.

Comment: +1 for *electrical devices in the racks of a data center are 100% efficient heaters* - And if you don't know all the ratings you can put a Kill-A-Watt on your whole rack.

Comment: The question mentioned UPSes too, and they also transfer most of their power to other devices. Though if the UPS is in the same rack, it doesn't matter as much which device converts the power to heat. (But you could have a bigger UPS in another room even, or you could have an UPS in the rack feeding that PoE switch feeding some other devices around the building...)

Answer (score 11):

> *Is there a general rule to calculate heat dissipation of electronic
> equipment*

The rule is: analyse the output power, realize it's virtually zero and use the input power as the value that generates heat.

- Does it emit light?
- Does it transmit radio waves?
- Does it emit sound?
- Does it perform mechanical work?
- Does it supply electrical power to something else?

If none of the above then, unfortunately, the efficiency might as well be assumed to be zero.

Comment: And even if they do, a rule of thumb that all the supplied energy ends up a heat us rarely far from the mark.

Comment: All energy is eventually converted to heat (photons), but the distinction is the power dissipated by the source versus that which goes elsewhere.

Comment: @Andy aka.  Ok.  So in the case of the radio repeater, where power requirement is 400W,and transmit power is 100W; then 100 watts are delivered to the antenna, but the remaining 300W are converted to heat inside the equipment room.  Makes sense.

Comment: @PStechPaul Heat is phonons, not photons. Photons are light or other EM radiation.

Comment: Thermal (black body) radiation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation is infrared, which is electromagnetic radiation just like radio waves and visible light, and that radiation also involves photons. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation Phonons appear to be involved in heat conduction in crystals and other phenomena. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays with AI you should be able to get most heat dissipation values. I myself am currently trying to find BTU/h for some equipments for a energy usage study I'm conducting in a ISP I work for. Though some suppliers promptly have this number, a few I had to get in contact with to get.
My guess is there is a standartized method to get this.
I came across this presentation I took the liberty to post at least on slide of it. I guess it is ok to share, sincce I found it with no effort at all.

num[image]ber

Comment: Joao Guilherme - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However, re: "*I guess it is ok to share*". Without further information, **no**. Currently your answer breaks the [site rule on referencing](/help/referencing) material copied/adapted from elsewhere. To comply with that rule, please [edit] the answer & add the PDF / video / webpage name and its link, for the source of that copied image. Also please remember it's your responsibility to follow that rule in future too. || As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as site rules here differ from typical forums. TY